# How can I bypass the "first setup"?

Tags: factory-reset

Is there a way to bypass the first setup screen, that shows up during first boot of a new/stock ROM or after factory reset?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes there is,** after the phone is opened and SetupWizard is on, starting with top-left corner of the screen, all corners must be tapped once, in a clockwise  direction. (Top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left to be more specific)

It can be hard to do it properly at first try so if it doesn't work, just try again.

[Here's a walkthrough video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWKXn2Vgkqo)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because it doesn't work. I am looking for a way to create a config file somewhere so that I can upload it to the phone. Now, I can access the file system of my android. But I just can't bypass the stupid "select language" screen.

Comment: @sgon00 You should take into account the fact that answers are written for the time that they are written. No one can predict how future functionalities will behave. Also, it is a well established method. It is not even a workaround or hack. It is a feature. If you can't run a feature, it is a mistake or error on your end, not the answer's.

Answer (score 1):

Today the answer is most likely no, this is not possible to skip the initial setup due to FRP.

From https://www.androidcentral.com/factory-reset-protection-what-you-need-know

> Factory Reset Protection (FRP) is a security method that was designed to make sure someone can't just wipe and factory reset your phone if you've lost it or it was stolen.